# How can I quit the application opened from terminal in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, shell

I know we can start an application from command line like:

```
 open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"/
```

How can I quit that application from command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
osascript -e 'quit app "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"'
```

As per [this page](http://osxdaily.com/2014/09/05/gracefully-quit-application-command-line/).

Or, as per the comments,

```
osascript -e 'tell app "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" to quit'
```

Comment: Or `tell app "Google Chrome" to quit`.

Comment: @slhck what is the difference between `quit app App` and `tell app App to quit`?

Comment: None that I know of. Personal preference :)

Answer (score -1):

Since you know the name of the process, you can use `killall`:

```bash
$ killall "Google Chrome"
```

Comment: But you **don't** know the name of the process in the general case. `open -a` takes an .app path, and `killall` takes a UNIX executable name, in this case situated in the MacOSX subfolder. The name of the UNIX executable is defined in Info.plist and is not guaranteed to match the name of the .app. The easiest way to prove this is by renaming an application and trying to kill it using `killall` and the new name. There may also be oddball applications where the developer just chose a different name for the two things.